# Upgrade Angular 7 -> 8 runs out of memory

Tags: angular, angular8

When I am running `ng update` to upgrade Angular 7 to 8, I am getting "Out of memory" error during @angular/core migration:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

which is not particularly surprising - I am getting `Out of memory` when I run `ng build` as well. As a solution, we run `npm run build` which is configured as `node --max_old_space_size=10240 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build`

So, my question is how do I configure migration for the package @angular/core to use more memory?

UPDATE: as suggested, I reran the update

```
node --max_old_space_size=10240 ./node_modules/.bin/ng update @angular/core --from 7 --to 8 --migrate-only
```

but I am getting an error:

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
      ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Seems like the quotes are for Linux environment and break on Windows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command `node --max_old_space_size=10240 node_modules/.bin/ng update` as explained in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14298) GitHub issue.

Update:

Looks like you can also customize `ng` command invocation as explained in [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://dev.to/koscheyscrag/fix-of-angular-cli-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error-while-running-ng-serve--1jjh&ved=2ahUKEwj6hZK0-8jiAhVEb60KHeW0CSEQFjAEegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3VnpzGBwWCNXzX0vMHO5DB&cshid=1559416883377) post.

Or you can upgrade node to the version 12, which should automatically adjust memory required to run the command.

Comment: the link is absolutely relevant - but I am trying to figure out *where* do I put this command?!

Comment: Could you use this command as a configuration for npm run upgrade? Or do you have some other requirements for where you should have the node commands? Could you please elaborate on how are you planning to run the upgrade. It seems that `ng update` would work on node 12 forward based on the comments in the GitHub issue shared above as the memory configuration is automatically adjusted.

Comment: Looks like you can also customize ng command invocation as explained in [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://dev.to/koscheyscrag/fix-of-angular-cli-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error-while-running-ng-serve--1jjh&ved=2ahUKEwj6hZK0-8jiAhVEb60KHeW0CSEQFjAEegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3VnpzGBwWCNXzX0vMHO5DB&cshid=1559416883377) post.

Comment: Please look at my update to OP... I think I am now getting windows-specific issue. Let me try to upgrade to Node 12 - one of the comments at your link says that it may solve the problem

Comment: I'm glad it worked, I have updated the answer if anyone else runs into this issue.